# gitolite: PTY allocation request failed on channel 0

Tags: gitolite

Both jenkins (the ci-server) and my git repository are hosted on the same server. The git repo is controlled by gitolite. If I access the repository from outside, for instance from my workstation I get

```
ssh git@arrakis

PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
hello simou, this is git@arrakis running gitolite3 v3.0-12-ge0ed141 on git 1.7.3.4

 R W    testing
Connection to arrakis closed.
```

Which is fine I guess (besides the PTY... warning)

Now back to the server, I'd like jenkins to be able to connect to my git repository as well.

```
jenkins@arrakis:~> ssh git@arrakis
gitolite: PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
```

Logging onto arrakis as user git (the gitolite user):

```
git@arrakis:~> cat ~git/.ssh/authorized_keys

command="/home/git/gitServer/gitolite/src/gitolite-shell jenkins",no-port-forwarding,no-x11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa <PUBLIC-KEY> jenkins@arrakis
```

The "no-pty" entry made me suspicious, so I removed it from authorized_keys and tried again:

```
jenkins@arrakis:~> ssh git@arrakis
hello jenkins, this is git@arrakis running gitolite3 v3.0-12-ge0ed141 on git 1.7.3.4

 R W    testing
Connection to arrakis closed.
```

This solves my issue at this point, but I'm not sure about the consequences of removing "no-pty".

And why does it only affect the local access, since the remote access doesn't seem to be affected at all?

---

openSUSE 11.4 (x86_64)
VERSION = 11.4
CODENAME = Celadon

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The difference in behavior between your workstation and your server is likely due to using different versions of the OpenSSH client (`ssh`) on each system (not remote versus local). The client will request a pty from the server unless `-T` is given, or the `RequestTTY` configuration option is set to `no` (the latter was first available in OpenSSH 5.9). The difference in behavior arises in how the client deals with having this request denied by the server (e.g. because `no-pty` is given in the applicable `authorized_keys` entry):

- Before OpenSSH 5.6:

  - the client will display the “PTY allocation request failed” message, and
  - **continue** in “no pty” mode
- In OpenSSH 5.6-5.8:

  - the client will display the “PTY allocation request failed” message, and
  - **abort** the connection
- In OpenSSH 5.9 (and later):

  - the client will display the “PTY allocation request failed” message, and
  - if `-t` was not given, and `RequestTTY` is `auto` (the default), then

    - **continue** in “no pty” mode
  - else (`-t` given, or the `RequestTTY` configuration option is `yes` or `force`)

    - **abort** the connection

Since your server’s `ssh` appears to abort when its pty allocation request is rejected, it is probably running OpenSSH 5.6-5.8 (at least for the client binary). Likewise, since your workstation’s `ssh` shows the warning, but continues, it is probably running an OpenSSH from before 5.6, or one that is 5.9-or-later. You can check your versions with `ssh -V`.

You can prevent the difference in behavior by using always giving the `-T` option so that the client (any version) never requests a pty from the server:

```
ssh -T git@YourServer
```

During actual Git access, the client never tries to allocate a pty because Git will give the client a specific command to run (e.g. `ssh server git-upload-pack path/to/repository`) instead of requesting an “interactive” session (e.g. `ssh server`). In other words, `no-pty` should not have been causing problems for actual Git access; it only affected your authentication testing (depending on which version of the OpenSSH client you were running) because the lack of a command argument causes an implicit pty allocation request (for an “interactive” session).

---

From the [OpenSSH 5.6 release announcement](http://marc.info/?l=openssh-unix-dev&m=128256356229601):

> - Kill channel when pty allocation requests fail. Fixed stuck client
>     if the server refuses pty allocation (bz#1698)

`bz#1698` seems to be a reference to a [report logged in the “Portable OpenSSH” Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1698).

---

From the check-in message of [OpenSSH clientloop.c rev 1.234](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.bin/ssh/clientloop.c#rev1.234):

> improve our behaviour when TTY allocation fails: if we are in
>   RequestTTY=auto mode (the default), then do not treat at TTY
>   allocation error as fatal but rather just restore the local TTY
>   to cooked mode and continue. This is more graceful on devices that
>   never allocate TTYs.
>
> If RequestTTY is set to "yes" or "force", then failure to allocate
>   a TTY is fatal.

Comment: Very thorough answer, and well explained... much appreciated!

Comment: My server runs on **OpenSSH_5.8p1**, OpenSSL 1.0.0c 2 Dec 2010 while my desktop pc is using **OpenSSH_5.9p1**, OpenSSL 0.9.8t 18 Jan 2012. So everything is exactly how you described it. Although I'm not sure about your statemant about "no-pty" not having any negative side effects on the bare git communication. I only stumbled over this issue because of my jenkins builds failed due to the aborted server connection. As soon as I removed the "no-pty" entry the problem disappeared. Maybe the culprit is the repository URL git@arrakis:myproject that was used to configure the jenkins git plugin.

Comment: Nevermind I just doubble checked so the communication with git works as suggested regardless of the "no-pty" entry.

Comment: These answers are the main reason to love Stackoverflow. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

To know why it affects only the local access, you would need to debug it like [in this article](http://platonic.techfiz.info/2008/10/13/pty-allocation-request-failed-on-channel-0/).

```
ssh -vvv git@arrakis
```

If your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` SSH daemon config file contains the (un-commented) line `SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV`, you can have a look at your SSH logs in `/var/log/secure`.

That being said, check out [GitoliteV3](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/g3why.html): I don't think it uses `no-pty` in the current setup.

Answer (score 1):

Beside Chris Johnsen very complete answer note that giving explicitely the `info` command will not show the PTY warning:

```
ssh git@arrakis info
```

In that case SSH considers that this is not an interactive session and will not request a TTY.