# What is Pseudo TTY-Allocation? (SSH and Github)

Tags: github, ssh, openssh

I was trying to setup an SSH connection with Github following this tutorial:

- [Testing your SSH connection](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/testing-your-ssh-connection)

I came across the following command:

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com 
# Attempts to ssh to github
```

Curious, I looked at the ssh manual. It said the following:

```
 -T      Disable pseudo-tty allocation.
```

What is tty allocation? What does tty stand for? Why are we disabling it?
I earnestly tried to look it up but I was unable to find even a definition.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with [Pseudo terminals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo_terminal)? Also, did you really find nothing of use when you [googled pseudo tty-allocation](https://www.google.com/search?q=pseudo-tty+allocation)?

Comment: Who knew pseudo terminals had anything to do with tty. I actually did find that link but thought it had nothing to do with tty allocation, heh. Thanks!

Comment: I was setting up SSH connection, I was following the same tutorial, and I was like what's this -T option, out of curiosity I looked at the ssh man page, and then I had the same questions you had!

Answer (score 134, accepted):

As explained in "[gitolite: PTY allocation request failed on channel 0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10346575/6309)", it is important to do ssh test connection with `-T`, because some server could abort the transaction entirely if a [**text-terminal (tty)**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal) is requested.

`-T` avoids requesting said terminal, since GitHub has no intention of giving you an interactive secure shell, where you could type command.

GitHub only wants to reply to your ssh request, in order to ascertain that the ssh command does work (you have the right public/private keys, and the public one has been registered to [your GitHub account](https://github.com/settings/ssh))

[PuTTy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY) would be an example of a [terminal emulator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator), [serial console](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_console) and network file transfer application. It supports several network protocols, including SCP, SSH, Telnet and rlogin.
The name "`PuTTY`" has [no definitive meaning](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/faq.html#faq-meaning), though **"tty" is the name for a terminal in the Unix tradition, usually held to be short for [Teletype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teletype_Corporation)**.

---

### Other use-cases for `-T` (beside testing)

- [Transferring binary files](https://serverfault.com/a/746638/783)
- [Execute commands on a remote server](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/88616/7490)
- SSH tunneling: `ssh -fnT -L port:server:port user@server` (-f for background: you don't want to execute command, don't need a TTY and just want to establish a tunnel)

Comment: thanks. is -T only used for testing connection, since it avoids allocating tty?

Comment: @Tim No, it can be useful (to disable tty) when transferring binary files (http://serverfault.com/a/746638/783) or to execute commands on a remote server (http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/88616/7490)