# what does the -i flag do in docker?

Tags: docker

I was just reading **[THIS](http://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerizing/)** article on Docker , Its an article describing how to dockerize a simple application. The following command is executed:

```
$ docker run -t -i ubuntu:14.04 /bin/bash,
```

and then, The following explanation is given:

> Here we’ve again specified the docker run command and launched an
>   ubuntu:14.04 image. But we’ve also passed in two flags: -t and -i. The
>   -t flag assigns a pseudo-tty or terminal inside our new container and the -i flag allows us to make an interactive connection by grabbing
>   the standard in (STDIN) of the container.

I don't understand the meaning of:

```
-i flag allows us to make an interactive connection by grabbing the standard in (STDIN)
```

Thank you.

Comment: .... interactive?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Docker's `-i`/`--interactive` allows you to send commands to the container via standard input ("STDIN"), which means you can "interactively" type commands to the pseudo-tty/terminal created by the `-t` switch.

Comment: whats the difference between interactively vs non-interactively ?

Comment: non-interactive means that you can't pass in text to the tty you allocated with `-t`.  interactive means you can type commands and the tty in the container will receive this text.

Comment: I am still confused.  The meaning of `-i`, according to the docs, is "Keep STDIN open even if not attached".  That suggests to me that `-i` should be unnecessary when STDIN is attached and only be needed when the `-d` option or an explicit `-a` not including STDIN is used.  However, this is obviously wrong since if I run `docker run -t ubuntu cat`, it doesn't echo input; I have to add `-i` to get that; but I don't understand neither why `-i` is necessary here nor why anyone would want the behavior of `-t` without `-i`.  Nor do I see if `-i` is useful with `-d` or `-a`, as the docs imply.

Answer (score 8):

I [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35551071/6309) that `-i`, `--interactive` keeps STDIN open even if not attached, which you need if you want to type any command at all.

That helps for pipes:

```
$ echo hello | docker run -i busybox cat
  hello
```

Meaning: [`-i` does not always need -t (`tty`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35462735/6309), with [`tty` being the text-terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17907289/6309).

Comment: What does "not attached" mean, exactly?

Comment: @VladimirPanteleev Attached to a tty. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/36565383/6309 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/35462735/6309

Comment: OK, though it would help to clarify what exactly is "attached to a TTY". So, I understand that "not attached" used to mean "`-a` is not specified", but the meaning of `-a` changed and now it's less obvious. So, to be more precise, if `-d` is not specified, lack of `-i` and `-a` is the same as `-a stdout -a stderr`, but with `-i`, it's the same as `-a stdin -a stdout -a stderr`.

Comment: @VladimirPanteleev Yes, `-i` would asdd the `-a stdin` indeed. `-i` keep the the container’s stdin available, either to a pseudo tty (`-t`), or to any pipe, when run with `-d`,  in background mode.

Answer (score 6):

From the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#foreground):

> For interactive processes (like a shell), you must use `-i -t` together
>   in order to allocate a **tty** for the container process. `-i -t` is often
>   written `-it` as you’ll see in later examples. Specifying `-t` is
>   forbidden when the client is receiving its standard input from a pipe,
>   as in:

```
$ echo test | docker run -i busybox cat
```

The -t flag is how Unix/Linux handles terminal access. Historically, a terminal was a hardline connection, with real pieces of hardware.

Today however, a pseudo-terminal driver is used.

- Run a container with no flags and by default you have a **stdout** *(standard output)* stream.
- Run with the `-i` flag, and you get a **stdin** *(standard input)* stream added, which accepts text as input.
- Run with -t, usually with the -i and you have a terminal driver added, which if you want to interact with the process is likely what you want. It basically makes the container start to look and feel like a terminal session.

Running `-t` without `-i`, means that you will have the terminal, but your input will not be connected to the terminal input.

Comment: In what cases do we need `-t` without `-i`? If there is no case, why don't Docker just make `-t` get stdin automatically?