# When would I use `--interactive` without `--tty` in a Docker container?

Tags: docker

I did some googling and have had no luck finding a case where I'd run `docker run -i some_image` rather than  `docker run -it some_image`.

If I run `docker run -i --name sample some_image bash`, the container runs in the foreground, but I can't interact with it from the shell I'm in. I can't even stop it with CTRL+C. I can, however, pop open another shell and run `docker exec -it sample bash` and gain access to the container.

If I run `docker run -i -d --name sample some_image bash`, the container immediately exits. I can restart it with `docker start sample` and then it stays up, so I can run `docker exec -it sample bash` and interact with it again.

However, in all these cases, I ultimately end up using `-it` to interact with my containers. In what world would I not need the `-t` flag?

Cheers

Comment: II can't figure out what would be the expected outcome of `-i -d`

Comment: @Auzias `-i -d` is in the example I link below with https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/e4cfd9b3924fae0369956b4f0e7f73a7e3b0cbf7/integration-cli/docker_cli_attach_test.go#L139: you launch and detach a process, to which you can attach to and use stdin to feed said process with data.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Since `-i` keeps STDIN open even if not attached, it allows for composition (piping).
For example:

```
docker run --rm ubuntu printf "line1\nline2\n" | docker run --rm -i ubuntu grep line2 | docker run --rm -i ubuntu sed 's/line2/line3/g'
```

<sup>(Source: [issue 14221](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/14221#issuecomment-115959209))</sup>

Or:

```
$ echo hello | docker run --rm -i busybox cat
  hello
```

<sup>(Source: [issue 12401](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/12401#issuecomment-93451074))</sup>

> Now imagine this not in front of a keyboard and being used in a script where you can actually write to the processes stdin through something better than a shell `|`: example [`integration-cli/docker_cli_attach_test.go`](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/e4cfd9b3924fae0369956b4f0e7f73a7e3b0cbf7/integration-cli/docker_cli_attach_test.go#L139)

As noted in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35459652/when-would-i-use-interactive-without-tty-in-a-docker-container/35462735#comment132653913_35462735) by [Pixelbog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17113459/pixelbog), adding the `--rm` option avoid leaving a bunch of '`Exited`' containers.

Comment: Could you please step-by-step explain what is exactly going on in the first snippet? Does it end up creating 3 different containers? Does `printf "line1\nline2\n"` run inside the first container? Does the first container write `"line1\nline2\n"` to host console? Do the containers exit after printing "hello"?

Comment: @gisek 3 containers are run in succession, each tome terminating right after their `echo`/`sed` operation.. The `-i` allows for the stdin to get the stdout produced by the previous container.

Comment: Thanks. After it all finishes, do we end up with 3 newly created stopped containers?

Comment: @gisek Yes. A `docker container prune` will take care of them (docker 1.13+/docker 17.03 ce: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32723127/6309)

Comment: @AndrzejGis couple of years too late, but you can also do: `docker run --rm ...`, so docker will delete these newly created, now stopped containers :)

Comment: @Pixelbog Good point. I have included the `--rm` option in the answer.