# What is the purpose of the "-i" and "-t" options for the "docker exec" command?

Tags: linux, docker, tty

To be honest, I have always been confused about `docker exec -it …`, `docker exec -i …` and `docker exec -t …`, so I decide to do a test:

1. `docker exec -it …`:

   ```
   # docker exec -it 115c89122e72 bash
   root@115c89122e72:/# ls
   bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
   ```

   It works normally.
2. `docker exec -i …`:

   ```
   # docker exec -i 115c89122e72 bash
   ^C
   ```

   The command hangs and I have to use <kbd>Ctl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> to interrupt it.
3. `docker exec -t …`:

   ```
   # docker exec -t 115c89122e72 bash
   root@115c89122e72:/# ls
   ^C
   ```

   It enters the container successfully but hangs on executing the first command.

So it seems there is no point in having the `docker exec -i …` and `docker exec -t …` commands. Could anyone elaborate on why there exist `-i` and `-t` options for the `docker exec` command?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`-i`, `--interactive` keeps STDIN open even if not attached, which you need if you want to type any command at all.

`-t`, `--tty` Allocates a pseudo-TTY, a [pseudo terminal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo_terminal) which connects a user's "terminal" with stdin and stdout. (See [`container/container.go`](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/074442df7a542f8604d28e38139488cae196f7d4/container/container.go#L359-L373))

If you do an echo, only `-t` is needed.
But for an interactive session where you enter inputs, you need `-i`.

Since `-i` keeps stdin open, it is also used in order to pipe input to a detached docker container. That would work even with `-d` (detach).
See "[When would I use `--interactive` without `--tty` in a Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35462735/6309)":

```
$ echo hello | docker run -i busybox cat
  hello
```

---

> `-i` keeps STDIN open even if not attached, what is the status of STDOUT in this case?

It is, for `docker exec`, the one set by `docker run`.

But, regarding [`docker exec`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/), there is a current issue ([issue 8755: Docker tty is not a tty with `docker exec`](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/8755)

> unfortunately your discovery only amounts to a difference between the behaviour of tty in centos6 vs ubuntu:14.04. There is still not a functional tty inside the exec - just do `ls -la /proc/self/fd/0` and see that it's a broken link pointing to a `pts` which doesn't exist.
>
> the actual bug we're dealing with is that certain standard libraries assume that the symlinks in /proc/self/fds/ must be valid symlinks
>
> The problem is that the tty is created outside on the host and there is no reference to it in the container like how `/dev/console` is setup in the primary container.
> One options to fix this would be allocate and bind mount the `devpts` from the host in to the containers.

Note (Q4 2017): [this should been fixed by now (docker 17.06-ce)](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/8755#issuecomment-311824902).
See [PR 33007](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/33007#issuecomment-299917413).

That PR now allows (since 17.06):

```
zacharys-pro:dev razic$ docker run --rm -t -d ubuntu bash
83c292c8e2d13d1b1a8b34680f3fb95c2b2b3fef71d4ce2b6e12c954ae50965a

zacharys-pro:dev razic$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
83c292c8e2d1        ubuntu              "bash"              2 seconds ago       Up 1 second                             xenodochial_bardeen

zacharys-pro:dev razic$ docker exec -ti xenodochial_bardeen tty
/dev/pts/1
```

(before 17.06, `tty` was returning "`not a tty`")

Comment: `-i` keeps STDIN open even if not attached, what is the status of STDOUT in this case?

Comment: @NanXiao that depends on the image. See the edited answer.

Comment: Sorry for interrupting you again. Actually, the question I want to ask is the STDOUT is always open, right? Thx!

Comment: @NanXiao it is opened if the docker run had allocated stdout (in that case, docker exec does not need -i, it will use the one set by docker run, except on CentOS6, where it will not work, hence the bug I mention)

Comment: @NanXiao See also https://andykdocs.de/development/Docker/Fixing+the+Docker+TERM+variable+issue for illustration of the need for docker run to have set a tty.