# docker mounts host's / directory to container's / in debian wheezy 7.8

Tags: docker, debian

I am creating a very basic image on my debian wheezy host machine. This is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty
USER root

# Activate multiverse repos
RUN echo 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe multiverse' >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN echo 'deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe multiverse' >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN echo 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe multiverse' >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y supervisor

WORKDIR /

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-n"]
```

To build the image, I used `docker build -t basic-ubuntu .`

To run the container, I used `docker run -d basic-ubuntu`

To go into the container, I used `docker exec -i -t <container_id> bash`

When I am into the container, what I see is that the container's root directory `/` has the same content as the host. When I create a file on the container, it's also created on the host. Even when I add in the Dockerfile a `RUN apt-get install -y` of some package I don't have on the host, then I don't find it on the container. Actually even the $PATH variable on the container is the same as the host.

Here are some info on my env

```
host$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 7.8 (wheezy)
Release:        7.8
Codename:       wheezy

host$ docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.10.1
 API version:  1.22
 Go version:   go1.5.3
 Git commit:   9e83765
 Built:        Thu Feb 11 19:20:12 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.10.1
 API version:  1.22
 Go version:   go1.5.3
 Git commit:   9e83765
 Built:        Thu Feb 11 19:20:12 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

The mounts shown by docker  inspect

```
"Mounts": []
```

For the full docker inspect trace: http://pastebin.com/t4uSu4ZH

I think that the problem comes from the docker exec step. Because the build and run seem to work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think that the problem comes from the `docker exec` step

That is certainly the case, considering a container is there to **isolate** you from the host.
(different filesystem, process, root, user, ...)

When you "exec bash" to a container, you should see a prompt:

```
 root@<short_container_id>
```

If you don't see that, it is because somehow your docker exec did not execute properly.

If you do see that, then what you think is on the host is actually still the container content.

Also relevant, there is a potential bug around `-i` (interactive) when used with `docker exec`.
See "[Why do there exist “`-i`” and “`-t`” options for the “`docker exec`” command?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35551071/6309)".

The [OP amine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2561439/amine) confirms it is the case [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35672447/docker-mounts-hosts-directory-to-containers/35672728#comment59033374_35672728):

[Issue 8755 ("Docker tty is not a tty with docker exec")](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/8755) means `-t` (tty) does not correctly opens a tty on centos7 (not centos6).

This happens even if `TERM` is set to `xterm` (don't forget [issue 9299](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/9299): `docker exec` does not set `TERM` env when `-t` passed)

---

The other issue mentioned by the Op is:

> When I went back to the [howto install docker in debian](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/debian), I found that in the prerequisites: "`kernel must be 3.10 at minimum`" and "`These older versions are known to have bugs`".
>   And my debian's kernel version is 3.2.
>   **The solution was to upgrade to a newer debian version, with a kernel version above 3.10**.

Comment: No I don't have that problem:

`myuser@myhostname$ docker exec -i -t 151961654ce5467cff51c606d6e9886c01008c4a9a81c0076715dfca77318f73 bash`

`root@151961654ce5:/#`

Comment: And creating a file there creates it on your host too? Since you have not mounted a volume (https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-file-as-a-data-volume), that is unlikely.

Comment: Yes that happens and it's totally weird I agree

Comment: @amine Are you *sure* though? How do you check that the file exist on the host, and not just on the container?

Comment: `root@151961654ce5:/# echo "foo" > bar.txt`

`root@151961654ce5:/# exit`

`myuser@myhostname$ cd / && cat bar.txt`

`foo`

Comment: @amine ok, the CMD supervisord must be the weird element there. Can you rebuild the image with a simpler `CMD [ "while true; do sleep 1; done" ]`?

Comment: when running, it lead to `docker: Error response from daemon: Container command not found or does not exist..` and the container's status is `Created`

Comment: @amine OK. Can you simply remove the CMD from the Dockerfile, rebuild it, and try a `docker run -it --rm <yourImage> bash`. In that session, create a file, and in another shell, see if that file appears on your host.

Comment: that worked fine. it's different from the host's content

Comment: @amine At least, that is finally what I expected. Now why the daemonize version of your container *seems* to behave strangely?

Comment: @amine can you try again, with no CMD, and a `docker run -d <yourImage> sh -c "while true; do sleep 1; done"`

Comment: the container starts but when using `docker exec -i -t <containerId> bash` same problem as always, host's content shows in container

Comment: @amine can you try again, this time (after killing the container) adding the -i option: `docker run -id <yourImage> sh -c "while true; do sleep 1; done"`. Also, if the issue persists, that could be because of http://stackoverflow.com/a/35551071/6309

Comment: same. nothing changed

Comment: @amine Then issue https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/8755 could be at play here.

Comment: yes this seems to be the same issue. I have another host machine running ubuntu (and another version of docker I think). I will run the image on it and see if it reproduces

Comment: tested on a ubuntu trusty with docker 1.10.2 and it works without any bug. @VonC please update your reply with the github issue link and thanks a lot for your help

Comment: FYI when I went back to the howto install docker in debian https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/debian, I found that in the prerequisites: "kernel must be 3.10 at minimum" and "These older versions are known to have bugs". And my debian's kernel version is 3.2. The solution was to upgrade to a newer debian version, with a kernel version above 3.10. And this is the procedure I followed https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-upgrade-debian-linux-system-from-wheezy-to-jessie-stable-release I hope that could help people having this kind of issue

Comment: @amine Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue where `docker volume mount function` was not working correctly . And this turned out to be the kernel version issue. After I upgrade my Debian kernel from 3.2 up to 3.16, everything works fine.

```
$ uname -a
Linux 3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt20-1+deb8u3~bpo70+1 (2016-01-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```