# Confuse about docker's -i "Keep STDIN open even if not attached"

Tags: docker

The `-i` flag is described as "Keep STDIN open even if not attached", but [Docker run reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#foreground) also says:

> If you do not specify -a then Docker will attach all standard streams.

So, by default, stdin is attached, but not opened? I think it doesn't make any sense when STDIN is attached but not opened, right?

Answer (score 9):

[The exact code](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/75a7f4d90cde0295bcfb7213004abce8d4779b75/commands.go#L1797-L1806) associated with that documentation is:

```
// If neither -d or -a are set, attach to everything by default
if len(flAttach) == 0 && !*flDetach {
    if !*flDetach {
        flAttach.Set("stdout")
        flAttach.Set("stderr")
        if *flStdin {
            flAttach.Set("stdin")
        }
    }
}
```

With:

```
flStdin := cmd.Bool("i", false, "Keep stdin open even if not attached")
```

In other words, stdin is attached *only* if `-i` is set.

```
        if *flStdin {
            flAttach.Set("stdin")
        }
```

In that sense, "all" standard streams isn't accurate.

As commented below, that code (referenced by the doc) [has since changed to](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/07f580489908bf6a3373daac1473045406e1130d/runconfig/opts/parse.go#L102):

```
cmd.Var(&flAttach, []string{"a", "-attach"}, "Attach to STDIN, STDOUT or STDERR")
```

`-a` does not man anymore "attach all streams", but ["specify which streams you want attached"](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/07f580489908bf6a3373daac1473045406e1130d/runconfig/opts/parse.go#L138-L142).

```
var (
    attachStdin  = flAttach.Get("stdin")
    attachStdout = flAttach.Get("stdout")
    attachStderr = flAttach.Get("stderr")
)
```

[`-i` remains a valid option](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/07f580489908bf6a3373daac1473045406e1130d/runconfig/opts/parse.go#L150-L152):

```
if *flStdin {
    attachStdin = true
}
```

Comment: The source you provided is out of date. The latest link is [this](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/07f580489908bf6a3373daac1473045406e1130d/runconfig/opts/parse.go#L138). However, it seems that I can force set attach STDIN, for example `docker run -a stdin python:2` which will set attachStdin true.

Comment: @Yon True, I have edited the answer accordingly, illustrating the new meaning of `-a`.

Comment: Thanks. But, I still don't know is there any chance that make `attachStdin` true while `flStdin` false is useful? If not, why don't just set `attachStdin = flStdin`

Comment: @Yon It seems it is just another way to specify you want stdin attached: `-a stdin` and `-i` are equivalent.

Comment: No, I don't think so. `docker run -a stdin -a stdout -a stderr -t python:2` and `docker run -it python:2` is not same, I can not input anything in the former.

Comment: @Yon You should, does piping work? (http://stackoverflow.com/a/35462735/6309) Can you try with -t? (http://stackoverflow.com/a/35551071/6309)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108891/discussion-between-yon-and-vonc).

Comment: Never mind. Here is what I said in chat, "`echo hello | docker run -i busybox cat` prints `hello` as expected, while `echo hello | docker run -a stdin -a stdout busybox cat` prints nothing..."

Comment: @Yon Strange, and `echo hello | docker run -t -a stdin -a stdout busybox cat`?

Comment: `cannot enable tty mode on non tty input`,  pipe is conflict with `-t`

Comment: @Yon makes sense. That seems confusing, as the code seems to make `-i` and `-a stdin` identical (in that both attach stdin)

Comment: From code, `-i` is passed to container's config ([link](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/07f580489908bf6a3373daac1473045406e1130d/runconfig/opts/parse.go#L380)), so in my opinion,  `-i` is about **open STDIN in container**, `-a` is about **attach host's STDIN  to container's STDIN** (same for STDOUT and STDERR). I just don't know why docker allow attaching STDIN to container's STDIN even if it is not open.

Comment: Maybe I need to dive into code more, however I don't know Go. (⊙_⊙)

Comment: @Yon -i is used for piping from host to container though.

Comment: I think it is because `-i` will force attach STDIN and open container's STDIN so that we can use pipe.