# ssh command -T option

Tags: unix, github, ssh, gitlab

I'm wondering what the `-T` option in the following command does, cannot see this option in the manual somehow:

```
$ ssh -T git@gitlab.com
Welcome to GitLab, Simeon !
```

Could somebody explain?

Comment: Perhaps your man page is defective. Take a look at this webified man page: [man ssh on openbsd.org](http://man.openbsd.org/ssh#T). It says that `-T` will -T disable pseudo-terminal allocation.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I [explained before what TTY was](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17907289/6309): a text terminal is needed when you open an *interactive* session to a remote server.

But: in the context of a remote Git repository *hosting* server (GitHub, Gitlab, BitBucket, ...), no remote server will ever allow you to open an interactive session (for security reason)

Then only reason why you would still do an `ssh -T git@github.com` would be to test if you are correctly authenticated, and the session would immediately end with:

```
Hi username!  You've successfully authenticated, 
but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Since no tty is needed for that test, you should use the `-T` option when making this test.

Comment: So, the ssh option -T means "non-interactive TTY terminal" basically?

Comment: @user3870315 Normally, `T` is about TTY, not "interactive", as illustrated with Docker (https://stackoverflow.com/a/35551071/6309). But with SSH, since stdin is generally not easily accessible (https://stackoverflow.com/q/1340366/6309), removing TTY renders the session effectively non-interactive indeed.